# Open .msg file over http with Outlook CLI

Tags: html, email, outlook

I need to automaticaly open stored .msg files with outlook CLI, in local my command works but not if I try to load distant file.

`<a href="outlook:<PATH OF THE MSG FILE>">MAIL</a>`

Commands executed after click (commands are saved in registry):

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Outlook.exe" /f "C:\blabla\mail.msg"`

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Outlook.exe" /f "http://blabla.com/mail.msg"`

It is possible to get distant mail ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Outlook can only open MSG files from the file system. Why do you specify "outlook" in your link? Just point it to an MSG file on the server - the browser will prompt the user and download it locally before launching the local application registered to open MSG files.

Comment: Okay, I'll do it like that.
The "outlook" was to open outlook directly as with mailto (see here [outlook protocol](https://www.slipstick.com/problems/outlook-missing-outlook-protocol/)) and use the cli switches.
It was for open the mail directly at the time of the click without show a download to the user.
Thank you for your answer

Comment: It would have been a security hole if you could do that... No way to avoid the download/open/save prompt.

Comment: Yes I see, but it's for internal use only, just on local website on my pc, so i'ts not so dangerous....I think

Comment: The browser does not know who the good guy is. Everybody has to suffer equally :-)